# ASP NET Core Identity. ReturnUrl

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I use ASP NET Core + Identity. When i'm not authorized to access a page i got this:

```
http://localhost:5087/Login?ReturnUrl=/Error/401
```

How should i get right ReturnUrl correctly?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseIdentity();
    app.UseMvc();
}

public IActionResult Error(string id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case "404":
            return File("~/errors/404.html", "text/html");
            break;         
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect : `http://localhost:5087/Error/401` ?

Comment: @MegaTron I expect  http://localhost:5087/Login?ReturnUrl=RequestedAction

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the object `return File("~/errors/404.html", "text/html");`
you want get the full rout, right?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error(string id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case "404":
            return File("~/errors/404.html", "text/html");
            break;         
    }
}
```